# Concatinate string and variable value

Tags: xml, xslt, svn, tortoisesvn

I try to modify the svnindex.xsl file that is used in Apache Subversion. I want to add the protocol for TortoiseSVN (**tsvn:**) to the link generated by mod_dav_svn.
It should look like "tsvn:[https://svn.example.com/repo"](https://svn.example.com/repo%22).
All I have is the block

```
  <xsl:template match="dir">
<div class="dir">
  <xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
  </xsl:element>
</div>
```

I know that I should do something here, but all my attempts are in vain.
And I can get "https://svn.example.com/repo**tsvn:**" without any problems, just by writing `<xsl:text>tsvn:</xsl:text>` after `<xsl:value-of select="@href"/>`

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: So add it before instead of after?

Comment: @michael.hor257k It didn't work. I get a blank page.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].